# node-amqp and async ack

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, amqp

I am working on a project that uses rabbitmq. The queue I have to work with (lets call it "testq" gets from time to time about 35000 items that have to be worked on.

basically (very short):

```
var q = new Queue();
q.subscribe('testq', { ack: true, prefetchCount: 100 }, function(doc, object, queueOptions, originalDocument) {
//do some action
originalDocument.acknowledge();

});
```

My problem now is: I want to get 100 messages at a time (prefetch count = 100), but when do I know that all 100 messages have been processed so that I can acknowledge and get the next 100 messages? The "do some action block" is async :(

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You acknowledge messages one by one and you should not worry about getting next 100 messages while it's a broker job to deliver messages to you. There is nothing wrong to have `do some action` asynchronous, just make acknowledge after `some action` is done, I guess it can be done via callbacks, as everything done in node.js. Something like that:

```
q.subscribe(
    'testq',
    { ack: true, prefetchCount: 100 },

    function(doc, object, queueOptions, originalDocument) {
        doSomeAction(function() {
            originalDocument.acknowledge();
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Will all the messages start at the same time, or will the next message wait til you ack previous message?

Comment: Messages are processed one by one, in order they was published. Prefetch count says that your consumer can hold no more than 100 not acknowledged messages. So if you will have 10 messages aked and other 90 not you will get only 10 new messages. Note, that if you use auto-acknowledge `prefetch count` ignored.

Comment: What would then be the best way to process messages in parallel? Call `q.subscribe()` x many times?

Comment: @zaq178miami Can I conclude from your comment that q.subscribe is serial?  It won't call the callback again until I ack the message?

Comment: Yes. For further reading please refer to https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp#queuesubscribeoptions-listener.